# How I can solve this error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-never

```
<div class="ContentDiv">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <app-patient
               *ngFor= "let x of Users"
               class='col-3'
               [name]= "x.name"
               [PassedPCR]="x.PassedPCR"></app-patient>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Angular, and above is the code that has a problem:

```
        <app-patient
           *ngFor= "let x of Users"
           class='col-3'
           [name]= "x.name"
           [PassedPCR]="x.PassedPCR">
```

By "x.name", I am expecting to call the names from an API using "fetch". But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can I see the User object please?

Comment: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }

Comment: declare the variable name like myArray : any[] = [your array]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the user does not have the "name" information.
what information is available to the user ?

Comment: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }

Comment: Can i see the part where you get the users in the ts file.

Comment: export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  Users = [];
  constructor() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json =>{
      this.Users=json;
      this.Users.forEach(element=>{
        element.PassedPCR = element.id % 2 == 0 ? true: false;
      });
  })
}

Comment: And this is the child component, ts file: export class PatientComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name = '';
  @Input() email = '';
  @Input() PassedPCR = true;

Comment: on your ContentComponent You can do a console.log of the json you retrieve to see if it is the list of users.

Comment: Use an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) when define your variable: `Users:User[]=[]` or use any:`User:any[]=[]`